# Get all data attribute order of HTML elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

In the `#content` div, there are blocks that user can drag them and sort them.
Each block may contain many nodes. Under each block, the are element that contains "`data-node-id`" attribute. i want to make a function that will get the order after drag-sort. this function can run from a click button (does not have to run for every sort-change).

Here is my page: http://orbitcoins.website/demos/demo%20-%20json_nodes_diagram/nodes_diagram_serverfile.php

So let's say, i have elements in this order:

```
order = {1,2,3,4,5}//block1:{1}, block2:{2}, block3:{3,4,5}
```

after changing the order of the second and the third block, When running this function, we will get this result:

```
new_order = {1,3,4,5,2}//block1:{1}, block2:{3,4,5}, block3:{2}
```

There is no difference when using JQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: Use `javascript php jquery html css` and have a try.

Comment: what you exactly want? question is unclear.

Comment: **Please may you add a clear problem statement, and a [mcve].** (Also, Objects in JS have no order. Instead use an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) `order = [0,1,2,3]`)

Comment: @Alive to Die There is no string that ends with a `?`. So no real question, more wants and needs.

Comment: i did, but since the elements are not child elements, i didn't figure out how to get always the right one

Comment: @AlivetoDie i wan't to get the order of the elements with "data-node-id" in my code. even when user drag and change the order.

Comment: `$("[data-node-id]").map(function() { return +this.getAttribute("data-node-id"); }).get()`

Comment: You can use the event 'drag' to detect which element is being dragged around. So just save the current order in an array and move the dragged element to it's new position in the array. You could map each element every time, but since you know the original render order and can detect the dragged element, no need to touch the DOM apart from the 'drag' event listener.

Comment: @Shilly i want to run the two scripts separately. is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Andreas Yes! your Code Is Working! thank you!

Comment: Ofcourse, but then Andreas' solution in the comment above is better, since you'll have to check all the elements again if you don't update each drag. Personally I don't like that sort of logic, since it means there's a time where the data model (the array) isn't consistent with the view (your html shown) . But that's just a computer sci kinda discussion. :)

Comment: @Shilly yes i tried it after replying to you, and it worked perfectly! it did what i wanted to. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, @Andreas has posted the solution in the comment:

```
$("[data-node-id]").map(function() { return +this.getAttribute("data-node-id"); }).get()
```

This solution seems perfect to me! it do exactly what i wanted to.

Credit Goes to @Andreas .

Comment: ES6: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[data-node-id]")).map(n => +n.getAttribute("data-node-id"));`

Comment: ES5: `var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("panel-success"); function getOrder() { var order = []; for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { order.push(+elements[i].getAttribute("data-node-id")); } return order; }`

Comment: actually, i only need the "`data-node-id`" not the entire element. your first solution seems exactly what i need. so i will keep your first solution.

Comment: They will all return the node ids only. For the ES5 version you will to call `getOrder()` to get the list. But this version will query the DOM only once in contrast to the other versions.

Comment: yes but the panel-success, isn't a stable class. it's a design class and can be changed, so the first still flexible perfect.

Answer (score 0):

With this snippet, you can check all blocks in the order you defined and get the contained values at the end of the execution:

```
    // all the blocks you have
    $blocks = array(1, 2, 3);

    // all the elements they contain
    $blocks[1] = array(1);
    $blocks[2] = array(2);
    $blocks[3] = array(345);

    // the new block order you will get
    $new_order = array(1, 3, 2);

    // initialize the new blocks order
    $new_blocks = array();

    // for every block of the new order
    foreach ($new_order as $block) {

        // add to the new blocks order the content of that block
        array_push($new_blocks, $blocks[$block]);

    }

    // for each new block obtained
    foreach ($new_blocks as $block) {

        // and for every node inside
        foreach ($block as $item) {

            // print it out
            var_dump($item);

        }

    }

    // new_blocks is the structure you are searching for
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but @Andreas used a map and it gives what i need in a simple code and i don't need to loop on blocks.